# How do I list OID Names along with their associated OnNotificationAction Triggers with PRTGAPI using Powershell?

Tags: networking, powershell, script, shell-script, network-monitoring

So I'm trying to pull a list of Group Names with their corresponding notification triggers using PRTGAPI,  Get-Sensor | Get-Trigger gives me ObjectId & OnNotificationAction but I am struggling to find a way to list the object name instead of the OID. This is probably an easy fix but I have to admit I'm a dunce when it comes to scripting and the closest I've gotten is something like this:

```
Get-Sensor | Get-Trigger | select * | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\austin\Desktop\prtg.csv'
```

Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You might need to give some examples of the data because more people will be able to help you then with sample data of what you are working with than those that have PRTGAPI and the PS commands to run against the data to assist. With some sample data like this is the output I am getting, this is the data in the csv, and this is the expected result of the data will help you get an answer quicker.

Comment: Thanks,,,  I'm pretty much just trying to make a spreadsheet that lists all the devices along with the triggers associated with them so we have a reference of who supports which devices.

Comment: Share the output of `Get-Sensor | Get-Trigger | select *` as a starting point. Really need to see some sample data to help here I think. This does seems like a simple request so I think people missing the data may be the issues with why you've not gotten any other advice yet. The output of the commands is what you need to put to a csv file, and that's what people are missing so you will need to share at least some data to show the output format. Rather than Select * perhaps you can select the specific fields you need to export to the spreadsheet if select * is too much to share.

Comment: Here you go,,, thanks! ObjectId
'ParentId
Inherited
Type
TypeName
SubId
State
Latency
Channel
Unit
UnitSize
UnitTime
Period
OnNotificationAction
OffNotificationAction
DisplayThreshold
Threshold
Condition
EscalationLatency
EscalationNotificationAction
RepeatInterval
Name
Id'